# Android Digest Authentication

Tags: android, authentication, digest-authentication

I'm trying to get Digest Authentication to work on Android. I'm using https://hc.apache.org/ which supports Basic and Digest I believe.

```
DefaultHttpClient dhc = (DefaultHttpClient) httpClient;
AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, AuthScope.ANY_REALM);

CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(authScope, credentials);

dhc.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
```

The server returns a `401` with the `Www-Authenticate` header indicating to use Digest Auth (providing the nonce, qop).

Then the second request is sent with the `Authorization` header containing the Digest. This request also returns a `401`.

[image]

Comment: Did you get this working? i am facing almost same issue in angular